# How to set path for authentication cookie

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, claims-authentication, cookie-path

In ASP.NET Core 6 MVC multi-tenant application tenants have different path base like `/tenant1` and `/tenant2`.

Middleware sets `HttpContext PathBase` from request url.

`SignInAsync` method always sets authentication cookie path to the root path `/`.

I'm trying to set authentication cookie path from `PathBase` using this code snippet:

```
Path = Request.PathBase.HasValue ? Request.PathBase.Value : "/"
```

The code shown below throws a compile-time error since `AuthenticationProperties` does not have a `Path` property. How to set cookie `Path` property so that different users can authenticated with different base paths?

```
public class AccountController : Controller 
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOn(string user, string password)
    {
        if (password != "secret")
            throw new ApplicationException("Bad password");

        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user) };
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties 
                                 {
                                     IsPersistent = true,
                                     AllowRefresh = true,
                                     // TODO: this throws compile error since Path property does not exist
                                     Path = Request.PathBase.HasValue ? Request.PathBase.Value : "/"
                                 };
    
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by writing your own [ICookieManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.icookiemanager) and setting it when adding cookie authentication scheme.
`ICookieManager` methods get `HttpContext` as input so you have access to `PathBase` from there.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie("Cookie", options =>
{
    options.CookieManager = CustomCookieManager();
});
```

Here's the default implementation of ICookieManager : [ChunkingCookieManager](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Shared/ChunkingCookieManager/ChunkingCookieManager.cs)

Comment: Thank you. I expected something simpler. Should I delete most of ChunkingCookiemanger source code and add setting Cookie Path from HttpContext.PathBase into it. Or is there better solution.

Comment: I don't know exactly what ChunkingCookiemanger does, so I suggest keep it all and only change the cookie path.